# Reverse a list Jess

Tags: jess

How can I reverse a list in Jess language? There is some function to do that?

For example:

```
 list -> a b c
```

Reversed:

```
 list -> c b a
```

Comment: Not out of the box. Do you want to miss the fun of writing this yourself? Hints: Recursive, length$, first$, rest$, insert$.

Comment: No, I can make a function using that